# How to run shell command in function and intercept standard output

Tags: shell, translation

Tell me how to use the `trans` command of the `trans-shell` package for
translation. I need to write a function that will intercept the output
translated text.

Comment: Cannot you use pipes ?

Comment: What is the connection with Emacs? If `trans-shell` is an Emacs package, can you add a link to it?

Comment: This is a command line utility, I want to use it in a translation function